# Altering the IBM DB2 9.7 STMTHEAP

Tags: db2

How can I get the current value of my DB2 9.7 DB's STMTHEADP, and how can I alter it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the command line. On Windows, search your Start Menu for Command Window - Administrator.

To get the current value, use the [GET DB CFG](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001954.html) command:

```
db2 get db cfg for MY_DATABASE
```

To set a new value, use the [UPDATE DB CFG](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0001987.html) command:

```
db2 update db cfg for MY_DATABASE using STMTHEAP 8192 AUTOMATIC
```

There's more info in the [STMTHEAP](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0000277.html) information center topic.

Answer (score 0):

Leons is correct, but if you ever need to figure out STMTHEAP size and don't want to use the command line, you can use the following SQL:

```
SELECT NAME, VALUE, VALUE_FLAGS, MEMBER
FROM SYSIBMADM.DBCFG
WHERE NAME = 'stmtheap'
ORDER BY NAME, MEMBER WITH UR;
```